# Elixir: Correct way of printing __STACKTRACE__

Tags: exception, elixir, stack-trace, rescue

I know we can get the full stacktrace using `__STACKTRACE__` in a catch/rescue block in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), but what's the correct way of printing it? In my case, I rescue from an error but I still want to log it to console. This is what I'm doing right now:

```ex
def unreliable_method(item) do
  # Do something with `item`
  :ok
rescue
  _err ->
    Logger.error("Failed for item: #{inspect(item)}")
    Logger.error(inspect(__STACKTRACE__))
    {:error, :processing_failed}
end
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Just the Stacktrace

This was answered by *Michał Muskała* on the [official elixir github issue](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/7097#issuecomment-443606715):

> The canonical way would be to use [`Exception.format_stacktrace/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Exception.html#format_stacktrace/1)

From the docs, it's clear that we don't need to explicitly pass `__STACKTRACE__` as an argument to the method when still inside the `rescue` block. It's automatically retrieved using `Process.info`:

```ex
Logger.error(Exception.format_stacktrace())
```

---

### Full Error *and* Stacktrace

Michal's comment helped me find [`Exception.format/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Exception.html#format/3), that formats the error itself *and* its complete stacktrace, and that seemed more appropriate for my usecase:

```ex
def unreliable_method do
  # do something
  :ok
rescue
  err ->
    Logger.error(Exception.format(:error, err, __STACKTRACE__))
    {:error, :processing_failed}
end
```

Comment: What is cool with `Exception.format/3` is that it takes the same arguments as `catch` does. Thus `catch kind, payload ->` maps onto `Exception.format(kind, payload, __STACKTRACE__)`.